# Big size shapefile

Tags: shapefile, image-segmentation

After a segmentation process I have obtained a huge shapefile that contains approximately 3 million entities.

The problem is that no process can be obtained on such a huge data using arcgis, qgis or erdas imagine.

Even adding a new field on arcmap for example is causing the program to shutdown.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How large is the file? Are you able to use a geodatabase?  There are significant limitations to the shapefile format.

Comment: Have you tried importing into a database?

Comment: it is approximately 700 mb in size

Comment: May I suggest you explain how you obtained such a shapafile and what is the aim of your manipulation ? If the tag "image segmentation" and erdas imagine software you mention points to image classification, then it could be you could go through some additional and quicker image processing.

Comment: it is a segmentation process of huge ndvi image (12000 * 12000 ) that outputs a labelled image. when conevrting the output image into polygon (polygonize) the mentioned output shapfile is obtained

Comment: 3m rows is on the low end of the "large", but certainly isn't "very large". How wide is the dBase table? Its limit is 4000 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to a SQLite database or create a File Geodatabase and import it into as a feature class.  It should perform better when sourced within a database (taking advantage of and applying spatial and attribute indexing).

Comment: Shapefiles also support spatial and attribute indexing, albeit without a standard form.